# React Native Redux issue

Tags: react-native

I am having an issue with adding favourite functionality for e-commerce app. Getting error of undefined.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMEJy.png)

```
    case TOGGLE_FAVOURITE:
 
        const exitsIndex = state.favouriteProducts.findIndex((meal) => meal.id === action.productId);
        if(exitsIndex >= 0) {
            return { ...state, favouriteProducts: state.favouriteProducts.filter((meal) => meal.id !== action.productId) }
        } else {
            const favMeal = state.availableProducts.find((meal) => meal.id === action.productId);
            return { ...state, favouriteProducts: state.favouriteProducts.concat(favMeal) };
        }
 
 
This is my action:
export const toggleFavourite = id => {
    return { type: TOGGLE_FAVOURITE, productId: id };
};
 
And this is my call function: 
 const toggleFavouriteHandler = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch(toggleFavourite(productId));
      }, [dispatch, productId]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found different solution. Now its working

```
case TOGGLE_FAVOURITE:
const addedFavourite = action.product;
const id = addedFavourite.id;
const product_name = addedFavourite.product_name;
const product_image = addedFavourite.product_image;
const product_description = addedFavourite.product_description;
const product_price = addedFavourite.product_price;
const category_id = addedFavourite.category_id;

let updatedFavouriteItem = new Product(
    id,
    product_name,
    product_image,
    product_description,
    product_price,
    category_id,
)

if(state.items[addedFavourite.id] != null){   

let updatedCartItems = { ...state.items };
delete updatedCartItems[action.product.id];
  return {
    ...state,
    items: updatedCartItems,
}
    }
    return{
        ...state,
        items: {...state.items, [addedFavourite.id]: updatedFavouriteItem }
    }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check for the initial state, when you are doing  `findIndex` on `favouriteProducts` , `favouriteProducts` is null.

so just check if
`state.favouriteProducts === null` and that should work

Answer (score 0):

To prevent `TypeError` you should check if `state.favouriteProducts` is `undefined` or `null`.

In this case, i would use:

```js
case TOGGLE_FAVOURITE:
  if (!state.favouriteProducts) return false; // you need this

  const exitsIndex = state.favouriteProducts.findIndex((meal) => meal.id === action.productId);
      
  if (exitsIndex >= 0) {
    return { ...state, favouriteProducts: state.favouriteProducts.filter((meal) => meal.id !== action.productId) }
  } else {
    const favMeal = state.availableProducts.find((meal) => meal.id === action.productId);
    return { ...state, favouriteProducts: state.favouriteProducts.concat(favMeal) };
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Know I am having issues with state: undefined is not an object: state.products.availableProducts.find.

Comment: @Oleg Can you show the 'useState' section where do you declares your state?